# Фонетический разбор слова

Tags: фонетика, согласные, гласные

Какие из них правильные утверждения относительно слова **прачечная**?

три глухих согласных звука

кол-во букв и звуков совпадает

три мягких согласных звука

есть непроизносимый согласный

первый слог ударный

**Обновление**

Я думаю, что правильные ответы это - первый и третий варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я думаю,что правильные ответы -- это
>   первый и третий варианты.

Вы правильно думаете относительно первого и третьего вариантов:

в **первом** глухие -- [п], [ч'] и [ш] (допустимо и [ч']): [п]ра[ч']е[ш/ч']ная;

в **третьем** мягкие -- [ч'], [ч'] и [й']: пра[ч']е[ч']на[й'-а].

Но забыли про **пятый** вариант ("первый слог ударный"): прАчечная.

==============================

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Про допустимость **праче[ч']ной**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://www.terver.ru/russian/proiznoshenie_sochetaniy.php
Сочетание чн, как правило, произносится как [чн], а в следующих словах как [шн]: скучно, конечно, нарочно, яичница, пустячный, прачечная, скворечник и в женских отчествах типа Никитична.

Comment: Я больше всё-таки доверяю "Большому орфоэпическому словарю русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты" (Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф.;  М., 2012) , чем этому сайту.

В словаре так:

праче[ш]ная и допуст. младш. праче[ч']ная.

Comment: ВОТ-вот, ДОПУСТИМО, а первое-ШН

Comment: А девочка учится, ей нужно учебное задание выполнить, писать в соответствии с нормой, а Вы ей - как допустимо, Нужна литературная норма

Comment: Вот видите, она приняла ВАш ответ, значит, сделает ошибку и ей снизят оценку, вы бы скинули ссылку, пусть сама решает.

Comment: Так "допуст." -- это тоже литературный, только менее употребительный вариант. А варианты с отступлениями от литературного произношения имеют совсем другие пометы: !не рек.; !неправ.; !грубо неправ.

===

А составителям заданий тоже неплохо было бы современные нормы знать, а не перепечатывать из допотопных учебников абы что.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарю ''Русское словесное ударение.Словарь нарицательных имён''.( на Грамоте.ру) только прачечная [шн]. Хотя мне вариант чн больше по душе.

Comment: Кстати, согласен со Славой: помета ''допустимо'' тоже считается литературной нормой.

Comment: Но во всех школьных учебниках /шн/ начиная со 2 класса, а мы с вами взялись помогать в учебном задании. В таких случаях, я думаю, нужно приводить все взгляды, а автор вопроса пусть выбирает, что подходит. Дело в том, что мне однажды такой разгромный комментарий пришёл: "Ставите здесь из себя знатоков-умников, а мне из-за вас  незачёт поставили". Выбрали лучшим НЕ МОЙ ответ, а  высказали почему-то мне.Хотелось сказать: "А я при чём?"Но мнение было обо всём сайте.

Comment: Людмила, возможно вы правы. В школьном задании выбрать лучше один вариант - основной. Просто не всегда, на мой взгляд, школьные учителя знают о допустимых вариантах. Мне доводилось с такими встречаться, которые не только не знали о существовании допустимой нормы того или иного слова, но и не признавали вариативную норму. Хотя сами педагоги не плохие.

Comment: В таких случаях самый милый вариант - учебник в лицо сунуть! )))

Comment: >Хотелось сказать: "А я при чём?"

При том, что НЕ НАДО решать ЗДЕСЬ домашние задания! Из-за этого сайт в окончательное ..но скатился!

Comment: stopkran, а вы считаете, что это домашнее задание? Автор вопроса привел свой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

[прачьшнъjь]- **норма,** но сейчас стали допускать и [чн], тогда верно.

1) 3 глух. согл. есть - п, ч, ш;

5) первый слог ударный.

Неверно № 3: 3 мягких согл.  **нет, только 2: ч,j;**.